# Toad for DB2 On Prem to On Cloud -Group execute - Minus query -Error SQL0206N

Tags: sql, db2, toad

I have one table in both DB2 on Prem  and on DB2 on cloud with same table structure.

I am using minus query as below and executing using group execute function in Toad for DB2 :

```
select * from prem.HST_Table
minus
select * from cloud.HST_Table
```

I am getting below error :

```
DB2 Database Error:ERROR[42703][IBM][DB2/AIX64]SQL0206N "SOURCE_SYSTEM" is not valid in the context where it is used.
```

Issue is with only 4 columns , if i exclude these 4 columns from minus query , it is executing successfully.

Out of 4 columns, 2 columns is defined by default values, DDL is as below

```
"SOURCE_SYSTEM" VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT 'FILE'
"RECORD_TYPE" VARCHAR(16) DEAFULT 'INSERT'
```

Remaining 2 columns are timestamp columns, DDL is as below

```
"COMMIT_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT
"EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT
```

Comment: The answer will be in the details that your question omits. Find the *actual* SQL that the on-prem Db2 executes, as distinct from the SQL that you submit.

Comment: @mao - could you please elaborate

Comment: We cannot see the DDL for prem.HST_Table or cloud.HST_Table (i.e. exactly how they are defined to Db2, they can be views and nicknames ), or which registry settings and dbm/cfg are set that may be relevant.  You ask for help but you need to give details.